# Combining a date field and a time field in Progress Open edge SQL statement within Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, openedge

So I have a query that I have been feverishly trying to get working and I feel like it should have been easy enough but I was very much wrong.

I have two fields that I'm trying to compare to the system date less two hours. So basically everything that has happened in the past two hours. 
The date is a date data type but the time is text data type.

Here is an example of one of the many ways I tried to execute it;

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   ExampleTable
WHERE
   TO_DATE( DateField || ' ' || TimeField ) >= sysdate -(2/24)
```

I've also tried converting each field within the TO_DATE(), converting just the time, converting all of them and sysdate using TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP and so many other variations. All the outputs throw an error of inconsistent data types.

Please assist if you can!

Comment: Please provide data sample

Comment: I have an example BI for download: https://gtatextiles-my.sharepoint.com/personal/cmayers_gtatextiles_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fcmayers_gtatextiles_com%2FDocuments%2FExample%2Epbix&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fcmayers_gtatextiles_com%2FDocuments&cid=408a8fa4-36f3-49a5-9683-5b0ccffa56a3

Comment: I can evaluate in DAX the date and time but rather than applying a filter to each measure, I figured it would be easier to just pull the data from the source for two hours. Unless there may be a way to filter a report for two hours worth of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a TimeField that is a character field to hand. In an OpenEdge environment the norm is to store time as an integer (seconds after midnight) and then display it with the required format: string( TimeField, "HH:MM:SS" ).

If it is an integer you can use the following SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM ExampleTable
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( SQL_TSI_HOUR, TIMESTAMPADD( SQL_TSI_SECOND, TimeField, DateField ), NOW() ) <= 2
```

If your TimeField really is a character field then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM ExampleTable
WHERE 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
    SQL_TSI_HOUR, 
    TO_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( CONCAT( TO_CHAR( DateField ), ' ' ), TimeField ) ),
    NOW()
   ) <= 2
```

But since that looks like it is going to be a complete table scan anyway, you may want to add a normal where clause to limit results to the last two days.

```
AND DateField > CURDATE() - 2
```

Comment: This works but there is one issue, the portion of your code "<= 2". What does the number denote? I have records that are within two hours right not but will not show up until I change the number to 6, not 3, 4, or 5 but 6. I'm not really sure why?

Comment: 2 should be the number of hours since the unit being requested from timestampdiff is sql_tsi_hour. What values do you see when you just add timestampdiff (without <= 2 ) to the select phrase?

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss. Here are some screenshots of what it is pulling. The "Time Difference" column is your TIMESTAMPDIFF contribution without the expression. https://imgur.com/a/HyPzuDb

Comment: Timezone perhaps?

Comment: Oh so you're saying it possibly could be the server time compared to my local time? That would make sense

Comment: Yes, or the timezone of now() vs the timezone of to_timestamp.